# View Model Base

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xaml

I needed to write code in WPF for a client. The application is done with prism (not my decision, they already had people working on it), so I got a sparkling clean new module to work in. Since this was my first time writing WPF code going to production, I wanted to handle the code in a good manner. I decided to go MVVM.

I structured the module as follows (I do need to move the `RelayCommand` and `ViewModelBase`):

- Services (`IItemTypeService.cs`, `ItemTypeService.cs`)
- ViewModels (`ItemTypeViewModel.cs`, `ItemTypeViewModel.cs`, `RelayCommand.cs`, `ViewModelBase.cs`)
- Views (`ItemTypeAdminView.xaml`, `ItemTypeDetailView.xaml`)

The `ViewModelBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The `ItemTypeAdminView` is the main view. `ItemTypeDetailView` is a user control and is put into the `ItemTypeAdminView`. The `ItemTypeAdminView` will in the future be expanded with other sections, and those sections will use the same information as the `ItemTypeDetailView`.

Therefore, I made a `ViewModel` for the `ItemTypeAdminView`, not for the `ItemTypeDetailView`. Every `ItemType` is coming from Linq2SQL (yes, I know about EF - I wasn't involved in this part), and is wrapped in a `ItemTypeViewModel` so it can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The code for the `ItemTypeAdminViewModel`:

```
public class ItemTypeAdminViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region private fields
    private ICollectionView collectionView;
    private IItemTypeService itemTypeService;
    #endregion

    #region automatic properties
    public ObservableCollection<ItemTypeViewModel> ItemTypes { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<CompanyGTIN> CompanyGTINs { get; private set; }

    private Company selectedCompany;
    public Company SelectedCompany
    {
        get { return selectedCompany; }
        set
        {
            selectedCompany = value;
            LoadCompanyGTINs();
        }
    }
    #endregion properties

    #region constructors
    public ItemTypeAdminViewModel(IItemTypeService itemTypeService)
    {
        this.itemTypeService = itemTypeService;
        Initialize();
    }
    #endregion

    #region private methods
    private void Initialize()
    {
        //Should I wrap in Try/Catch? Try/Catch is expensive, must find something else...
        ItemTypes = new ObservableCollection<ItemTypeViewModel>(itemTypeService.GetItemTypes());
        Companies = itemTypeService.GetCompanies();
        collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemTypes);
    }

    private void LoadCompanyGTINs()
    {
        CompanyGTINs = itemTypeService.GetCompanyGTINs(selectedCompany.ID);
        OnPropertyChanged("CompanyGTINs");
    }
    #endregion

    #region commands
    public ICommand GoToFirstItemType
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst(),
                () => collectionView.CurrentPosition >= 1);
        }
    }

    public ICommand GoToLastItemType
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToLast(),
                () => collectionView.CurrentPosition < (ItemTypes.Count - 1));
        }
    }

    public ICommand NextItemType
    {
        get
        {
            LoadCompanyGTINs();
            return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToNext(),
                () => collectionView.CurrentPosition < (ItemTypes.Count - 1));
        }
    }

    public ICommand PreviousItemType
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToPrevious(),
                () => collectionView.CurrentPosition >= 1);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And the code for the `ItemTypeDetailView` XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid DataContext="{Binding ItemTypes}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Description:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Manufacturer:" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Companies, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}}"
                      Name="ManufacturerComboBox"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=DataContext.SelectedCompany, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding ManufacturerID}"
                      SelectedValuePath="ID" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="10" Text="Manufacturer Product Code:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Text="{Binding ManufacturerProductCode}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="11" Text="Manufacturer Product GS1 Code:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" Text="{Binding ManufacturerProductGS1Code}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="12" Text="GS1GTINID:"/>
            <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="GTIN"
                      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.CompanyGTINs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding GS1GTINID}"
                      SelectedValuePath="ID" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Command="{Binding GoToFirstItemType}">&lt;&lt;</Button>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <Button Command="{Binding PreviousItemType}">&lt;</Button>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <Button Command="{Binding NextItemType}">&gt;</Button>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <Button Command="{Binding GoToLastItemType}">&gt;&gt;</Button>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <Button Command="{Binding New}">New</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I am really curious about what could be improved structure/code wise and/or what should be left out.

Answer (score 5):

ViewModel generally looks good though I would still propose some changes:

1. I do not see why do you need `collectionView` field. You're moving it's `CurrentItem` but neither it nor the entire view is exposed anywhere.
2. `public ICommand NextItemType`. Why do you have `LoadCompanyGTINs()` call here? You have several similar `Move...` methods but only here you have this call.

---

Regarding View:

1. You have strange layout in the inner `Grid`. It has two columns but you're setting inner `Grid.Control` attached properties to `1` and `2` instead of `0` and `1`
2. Generally `Bindings` in your view look **VERY** strange. First of all I would recommend never ever bind `DataContext` inside view (`<Grid DataContext="{Binding ItemTypes}">`). If something inside view has separate `DataContext` then it should be a separate `View+ViewModel`. Because of this binding you have to use `RelativeSource` inside for some other controls which is not good. The bindings inside first grid which do not have `RelativeSource` also look strange. For example `<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />`. With such binding I think it tries to locate a `Name` property on `ItemTypes` collection but this is an `ObservableCollection` which doesn't have such property so it should not work. The same about `Description`.
3. If you really need `RelativeSource` then at least try to avoid using it with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}`. I've tried to guess what will be the result `Source` for binding but had no luck. I would recommend using something like `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ItemTypeDetailView}` instead.

Generally I would insist only on getting rid of those weird bindings in your View, the rest is more or less ok.

Comment: Thank you for your review :-) **1)** I don't think I get this one. I use a field so that the commands (first, next, previous, last) can access that. **2)** You're right. That shouldn't belong there at all. I put it there to check something out and got sidetracked. **3)** Again - this was indeed wrong. Fixed it. **4)** You'd be right to think that `Text="Binding Name"` gets it from the ItemTypes collection, because that's what the containing `Grid`'s datacontext is set to. ObservableCollection indeed does not have a `Name` property, but the ItemTypes that are contained in it do.

Comment: **4) Cont'd** What I wanted to do here is not to have a ViewModel for the ItemTypesDetailView, but move everything up one level. Hence, the ItemTypes collection is in ItemTypeAdminViewModel and not have a ItemTypesDetailViewModel that has the ItemTypes collection in it. The reason for this is that there will be other User Controls that will also need some of the information of ItemTypes.
 **5)** I had to use `AncestorLevel=2` here because Prism modules do not have a Main Window, just a... eh.. 'Main' user control.